# Django template, send two arguments to template tag and return safe html value?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way to pass 2 arguments through django template tag and get a safe html value?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, You can use the built in template tag "safe"

```
{{ context_var|safe }}
```

Comment: im passing 2 values {% checkdatainicio data.one data.two %} and my return is: '<span style="color:#bdc3c7">'+data+"</span>"

Comment: i want to return it safe